# In Linux how to check if 2 different patterns are in consecutive lines

Tags: linux, file, awk, sed, hex

I've an ASCII text file which I'm validating. The file contains contexts of 2 types:

```
Necessary Context: One which should be present at least once in its exact position.
Optional Context: One which may or may not be present, but if present should hold its proper place.
```

The detail look of the file:

```
[INDEX] <-- optional context, but if present should be the first context immediately followed by [FEATURE_ID], else file invalid
[FEATURE_ID] <-- necessary context and should always be immediately followed by [FEATURE_REV], else file is invalid. If [INDEX] context there then this should be the second CONTEXT in file else first.
[FEATURE_REV] <-- necessary context (must exist one per FEATURE_ID) and should always be immediately after [FEATURE_ID], else file is invalid.
[PRL_ID] <-- optional context, but if present should always be immediately after [FEATURE_REV], else file invalid
[NO_OF_BYTES] <--optional context, but if present, should always be immediately after [PRL_ID] if it is present, else immediately after [FEATURE_REV] if [PRL_ID] not present. Otherwise file invalid.
[NO_OF_SIGNIF_BITS] <-- optional context, but if present should always be between [NO_OF_BYTES] ( can be only present if [NO_OF_BYTES] present else not) and [CRC], else file invalid
[CRC] <-- necessary context,(must exist one per FEATURE_ID and FEATURE_REV). This is always the last context.
```

Note, there might be multiple [FEATURE_ID] contexts in a valid File, and in all cases the other contexts leading and following it,  should follow same place holding rule. Something like this:

```
Validfile_1:

[FEATURE_ID]
[FEATURE_REV]
[CRC]

[INDEX]
[FEATURE_ID]
[FEATURE_REV]
[CRC]

Validfile_2:

[FEATURE_ID]
[FEATURE_REV]
[NO_OF_BYTES]
[CRC]

[INDEX]
[FEATURE_ID]
[FEATURE_REV]
[PRL_ID]
[NO_OF_BYTES]
[NO_OF_SIGNIF_BITS]
[CRC]

Validfile_3

[FEATURE_ID]
[FEATURE_REV]
[CRC]

Invalidfile_1 (order of contexts not ok):

[FEATURE_ID]
[INDEX]
[FEATURE_REV]
[NO_OF_BYTES]
[CRC]
[PRL_ID]

Invalidfile_2(FEATURE_REV or CRC can never exist without a FEATURE_ID):

[FEATURE_REV]
[NO_OF_BYTES]
[CRC]

Invalidfile_3 ( NO_OF_SIGNIF_BITS cannot exist without NO_OF_BYTES)

[FEATURE_ID]
[FEATURE_REV]
[NO_OF_SIGNIF_BITS]
[CRC]
```

I'm trying to achieve this in a linux script via multiple if else statements and `egreps`, but the lines of code are becoming more and complex.

The code that I'm going for:

```
f_id_c=`egrep "[ ]*\[FEATURE_ID=[0-9].*\][ ]*" $1 | wc -l`
f_rev_c=`egrep "[ ]*\[FEATURE_REV=[0-9].*\][ ]*" $1 | wc -l`
crc_c=`egrep "[ ]*\[CRC\][ ]*" $1 | wc -l`
[[ $((f_id_c)) -eq 0 ]] && { echo "Invalid! No [FEATURE_ID=] context defined in profile file !"; exit 1; }
[[ $((f_rev_c)) -ne $((f_id_c)) ]] && { echo "Invalid! Not all [FEATURE_REV=] contexts have leading [FEATURE_ID=] defined"; exit 1; }
[[ $((crc_c)) -ne $((f_id_c)) ]] && { echo "Invalid! Not all [CRC] contexts have leading [FEATURE_ID=] defined"; exit 1; }
for (i=0;i<f_id_c;i++)
  do
    // Have a check with SED that will confirm there is a [FEATURE_REV=] immediately following [FEATURE_ID=]
  done
```

Can someone suggest a compact `awk script` or `sed` manipulation where I can achieve all the above validation.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: @Harry Posted part of the code. Can you give me a way to check in `sed` or `awk` that if a pattern in line matches, then the immediately following line should match a certain pattern, else return false.

Comment: @EdMorton Sorry the explanation might be lengthier, but I don't understand where it got ambiguous ? I thought the requirement is pretty clear. Anyways have tried to modify the post little further, and also clarified where [CRC] can be. Kindly see if you can help. And yes the whole point of putting up the post is to get a precise `awk` script for it.

Comment: When posting sample input it's important to make it something that a proposed solution can be tested against. What you've posted so far doesn't contain any of the errors you want a script to catch so we could write a script that just does `printf ""; exit` and it'd produce the expected output given that input. Put some effort into coming up with an input file that contains some good records but also some that contain the types of error you want a tool to catch, and then also show the expected output given that input file. Otherwise there's nothing for us to test a potential solution against.

Comment: @EdMorton Understood the previous ambiguity you referred to. Changed the place-holding explanation of the contexts. Also added some example good and bad files.

Comment: Good. Does the script I posted produce any unexpected results when run against those files? If so, do you have any questions about any of that?

Comment: @EdMorton None unexpected. Tested with multiple error files. However I'll have to alter a few `allowed state transitions` a bit. Because just recollected that a `[CRC]` can only be present if `[NO_OF_BYTES]`present. But that I would be able to change in your AWK script. But with the question I posted, it works just fine, so thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want a FSM something like this:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    # define the allowed state transitions
    ns["IDLE","INDEX"]
    ns["IDLE","FEATURE_ID"]
    ns["INDEX","FEATURE_ID"]
    ns["FEATURE_ID","FEATURE_REV"]
    ns["FEATURE_REV","PRL_ID"]
    ns["FEATURE_REV","NO_OF_BYTES"]
    ns["FEATURE_REV","CRC"]
    ns["PRL_ID","NO_OF_BYTES"]
    ns["PRL_ID","CRC"]
    ns["NO_OF_BYTES","NO_OF_SIGNIF_BITS"]
    ns["NO_OF_BYTES","CRC"]
    ns["NO_OF_SIGNIF_BITS","CRC"]
    ns["CRC","INDEX"]
    ns["CRC","FEATURE_ID"]

    # create a regexp of the state names for use in match()
    for (state in ns) {
        sub(SUBSEP".*","",state)
        if (!seen[state]++) {
            states = states (states ? "|" : "") state
        }
    }

    # set the initial state
    state = "IDLE"
}

# parse the input
match($0,states) {
    nextState = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    if ( ! ((state,nextState) in ns) ) {
        print "ERROR", NR, state, nextState, $0 | "cat>&2"
        exit 1
    }
    state = nextState
}
```

When run against your posted sample input file:

```
$ cat file
....
[FEATURE_ID]
[FEATURE_REV]
...
...
[CRC]

[INDEX]
[FEATURE_ID]
[FEATURE_REV]
...
...
...
[CRC]
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
$
```

it produces no output, as expected since the sample you provided contains no errors for it to find.

Comment: Hi Ed, again revisiting this comment. I found the above not to be working with this file content: `[FEATURE_ID=4][FEATURE_REV=2]`. Basically this should be an invalid file as `[CRC]` is not present and it's a `necessary context`. How to work around this ?

Comment: Even for file containing only `[FEATURE_ID=4]` also doesn't show any error. My requirement is it should as the other `necessary contexts` are missing `[FEATURE_REV=]` and `[CRC]`

Comment: Yes, that's the problem with creating sample input/output in your question that doesn't adequately reflect your real data, you get a script that works for the sample you posted but doesn't work for your real data. It's like I always tell people - a script that produces the expected output given a specific sample input set is just the starting point for identifying a solution. No-ones going to notice if you update this question now so post a followup question with some **TRULY** representative sample input/output (really THINK about the error cases) and someone will help you.